# JavaScript.. Image() object as Array?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a simple 2D Tile-map HTML5... and I have images to use. Is tehre any way to turn

```
var imageObj = new Image();
```

Into an array so I don't have to do manual variables?

edit: I tried doing Array but I couldn't find the `src`. Wait.. I was like.. an Array doesn't have a `src`.. Hmmm.

Comment: Do you mean you want to turn the an `Image` object in to an `Array` object? Why would you want to do that? Of course an `Array` wouldn't have a `src` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make an array

```
var images = [];
```

and push all your Images to that array?

```
images.push(new Image());
```

Comment: `array()`? This is not PHP. Use `var images = [];` instead,

Comment: Wow. I am silly. I looked though my other projects and they ahd this. Ugh.

Answer (score 2):

Do a multidimensional array, like this:

```
var map = [];

for(var x = 0; x<MAP_WIDTH; x++) {
    map[x] = [];
    for(var y = 0; y<MAP_HEIGHT; y++) {
        map[x][y] = new Image();
    }
}
```

You can then access your images with `map[X][Y]` where X and Y are the coordinates of the tile you want to access.

*Minor note: Javascript doesn't support true multidimensional arrays, but this is close enough. It's actually a nested array, but yeah... probably more than you needed to know.*

Comment: And oh, you just want references to images, not a map made of images... *facepalm* Anyhow, this might come in handy at a future point, so I'll leave it up here.